# Locating most recently updated file recursively in UNIX

Tags: unix, automation, cron, unix-timestamp

For a website I'm working on I want to be able to automatically update the "This page was last modified:" section in the footer as I'm doing my nightly git commit. Essentially I plan on writing a shell script to run at midnight each night which will do all of my general server maintenance. Most of these tasks I already know how to automate, but I have a file (footer.php) which is included in every page and displays the date the site was last updated. I want to be able to recursively look through my website and check the timestamp on every file, then if any of these were edited after the date in footer.php I want to update this date.

All I need is a UNIX command that will recursively iterate through my files and return ONLY the date of the last modification. I don't need file names or what changes were made, I just need to know a single day (and hopefully time) that the most recently updated file was changed.

I know using "ls -l" and "cut" I could iterate through every folder to do this, but I was hoping for a quicker-running and easier command. Preferably a single-line shell command (possibly with a -R parameter)

Answer (score 2):

The `find` outputs all the access times in Unix format, then sort and take the biggest.
Converting into whatever date format is wanted is left as an exercise for the reader:

```
find /path -type f -iname "*.php" -printf "%T@" | sort -n | tail -1
```

Comment: Command looked good, but when I tried it out I got:

find: Arguments to -type should contain only one letter

Should I use "-type f" instead of "-type -f"?

Answer (score 1):

GNU find

```
find /path -type -f -iname "*.php" -printf "%T+"
```

check the find man page to play with other -printf specifiers.

Comment: Probably head a `sort`, and `head` after that? And `%T+` is a GNU extension, so might not be available on the OP's machine.

Comment: You need to remove the - from -f as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at a inotify script that updates the footer every time any other file is modified, instead of looking all through the file system for new updates.